# Running Inspiron 15R 5537 without a screen

Tags: laptop, bios, hdmi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R 5537 laptop with a badly damaged screen. The laptop boots to its current OS successfully, after the boot up external monitor connected via HDMI is detected and laptop can be used. I was hoping that by disconnecting the laptop screen connector from the motherboard the laptop would default to HDMI for output and I would see BIOS output on monitor connected via HDMI(such a setup works with Dell XPS 15 laptop), but after booting all I get is beeping from laptop and no output to external monitor. How do I get BIOS output to external monitor so that I could install a different OS to this laptop?

Comment: re-connect the laptop screen.